# How to dynamically change application Id in Kotlin DSL

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl, kotlin-dsl

Here my code snippet

```
val applicationId = when {
    this.name.contains("test") -> this.mergedFlavor.applicationId + ".test"
    this.name.contains("paidDebug") -> this.mergedFlavor.applicationId + ".dbg"
    this.name.contains("freeDebud") -> this.mergedFlavor.applicationId + ".dbg"
    this.name.contains("paidRelease") -> this.mergedFlavor.applicationId+ ".release"
    this.name.contains("freeRelease") -> this.mergedFlavor.applicationId+ ".release"
    else -> this.mergedFlavor.applicationId + ".development"
}
println(applicationId)
defaultConfig.applicationId = applicationId
println(this.applicationId)
```

But changing it to defaultConfig is not changing the applicationId.

Comment: Why you can't use `applicationIdSuffix` of flavors? Read here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id#change_the_application_id_for_build_variants

Comment: I have 34 different flavor in my app and 3 build types. Here in this 34*3 combination we have different applicationId. So, needs to change in this way